# Time complexity of list-length

Tags: performance, lisp, common-lisp, complexity-theory, time-complexity

I think `list-length` is a O(*n*) complexity operation, since it seems there's no other way to find it but going through all of the list's elements.

```
;; iterates through list's elements
;; and returns 6, right?
(list-length '(1 2 3 4 5 6))
```

Nevertheless, I'd like to be sure, since it's critical for a work of mine. Is this correct?

Comment: I remembered now to try to trace the function in clisp, it says:

"    0: (LIST-LENGTH (1 2 3))"
"    0: LIST-LENGTH returned 3"

So, at least it's not recursive...

Comment: The [documentation](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_list_l.htm) provides a non-recursive solution.

Comment: @chipalagusma It probably uses tail recursion.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes.

That's exactly right and I'm writing this sentence, because an answer needs at least 30 characters.

Answer (score 3):

The HyperSpec doesn't make a time constraint on [`list-length`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_list_l.htm), but it does provide an implementation that runs in linear time.  Since it *can* be implemented in linear time, it's hard to imagine why it *wouldn't* be.

It's worth noting, though, that depending on how `cons` cells are implemented, it might be possible to implement `list-length` in a way that `list-length` actually runs in O(n/k + k) time.  (This is, of course, still O(n), but it doesn't necessarily go through *all* the lists elements.)  For instance, if an implementation can get to a `cddr` without visiting the `cdr` (e.g., perhaps with some type of [CDR coding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDR_coding)?), then if it keeps a reference to the "current" cons as well as the previous one, it could get to the end of the list in n/2 time, and then check with one more reference whether the length of the list is n/2 or n/2 + 1.  I only point this out to highlight the fact that `list-length` (or `length`, for that matter) might not need to "visit" each element of the list, if the implementation provides a way of skipping past an element.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, you can implement your own wrapper for regular lists that keeps track of how many elements have been added to it, and that would make finding it's length O(1).

Comment: That's actually not obvious at all.  With structure sharing, you can easily have `tail == (d e f)` and `x == (a b . tail)` and `y == (c . tail)`.  If you add an element to `tail`, then you've increased the length of three lists, and there's no way to automatically update the cached lengths of `x` and `y`.  Structure sharing can be a big advantage, but it makes constant time `length` operations very difficult, if not impossible.  The wrapper you're describing is very  common, and not very hard to implement, but it's a very different thing than a Lisp list.

Comment: why not use a data structure with two elements: the first is a list and the second is the list length. Then write your own list manipulation functions that keep track of the length whenever they operate on one or more of your lists. I am pretty sure this is in SICP somewhere.

Comment: Yes, as I said, it's not too hard to come up with a sequence data structure that doesn't support any tail-sharing.  It's just not really a Lisp list anymore.  It'd no longer be a recursive data structure;  you wouldn't have, e.g., that a `wlist` (wrapped list) is either the empty wlist `wnil` or the `wcons` of an element and another `wlist`.